# extract fields till a string using awk

Tags: shell, awk

I have text like below. I want to extract all fields till `4 - Low`.

```
    STRY8 Extend main u 4 - Low Ready   (empty) (empty) 24
    STRY8929218 Analyse remediation plan    4 - Low Ready  (empty) (empty) 9
    STRY8929188 Service To Production   4 - Low Ready   (empty) (empty) 6
    STRY8929134  Max Connections  Automation    4 - Low Ready   (empty) (empty) 3
```

How can I use AWK to do this job. Any suggestions greatly appreciated.

Thank you.

Comment: Please add your desired output (no description) for that sample input to your question (no comment).

Comment: Do every line contain the text `4 - Low` ?

Comment: Are there really leading spaces in every line?

Comment: @Edvin Yes, It will have other similar patterns like ` 3 - Medium` but I believe I can manage that.

Comment: And @Cyrus, yes possibly.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `4 - Low` as field separator and output first column:

```
awk -F '4 - Low' '{print $1}' file
```

Output:

```
    STRY8 Extend main u 
    STRY8929218 Analyse remediation plan    
    STRY8929188 Service To Production   
    STRY8929134  Max Connections  Automation
```

Answer (score 2):

Could you please try following.

```
awk -v var="4 - Low" 'BEGIN{len=length(var)} match($0,/.*4 - Low/){print substr($0,RSTART,RLENGTH-len)}' Input_file
```

MORE Generic solution:

```
awk -v var="4 - Low" 'BEGIN{len=length(var)} index($0,var){print substr($0,1,index($0,var)-len)}' Input_file
```

Comment: Tried, but its also printing ` 4 - Low` along with output. I can grep it out but can it be done via AWK ?

Comment: @Edvin, thanks, changed it with variable approach, where we can mention any variable and it will catch string before it.

Comment: @rɑːdʒɑ, please check my 1st solution, which is more generic here.